# How to minify js file? change veryLoooooooongVariable to somthing like x?

Tags: javascript

For readability, I name variable to very long name, this will increase the size of js file, I'm thinking is it possible to automatically change these long name to short one by some tools/libs?

I would like to use these tools/libs to decrease the size of js in production web site.

I want the tools can do this:

change `var veryLooooongVariable` to `var x`

Comment: the web is full of js-minifier, did you tried to search for one?

Comment: Do you want to know _how_ to minify js or just websites to automatically minify js with? The latter is simple, use something like [this.](http://javascript-minifier.com/)

Comment: I thought these tools only remove blank lines, returns. They do not change `var veryLooooongVariable ` to `var x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alot of softwares to minify js and css as well [list of minifying softwares](http://listoffreeware.com/list-best-free-javascript-minify-software/) and there are alot of online minifiers as well like

- [js-minifier](http://javascript-minifier.com/)
- [js compressor](http://jscompress.com/)
- [clean css (js and css minifier)](http://www.cleancss.com/javascript-minify/)

and many more.

Comment: I thought these tools only remove blank lines, returns. They do not change `var veryLooooongVariable ` to `var x`

Answer (score 2):

To mangle your code use [uglifyjs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) or [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) - you may want to look into [Closure's advanced mode](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).